# PHP day of the year return n-1

Tags: php, date

A simple snip :

```
$day_today = date("z");
echo $day_today;
```

Returns `160` but today is `161`.

How to correct this ?

Thanks.

Comment: The day of the year (__starting from 0__)

Comment: `echo $day_today+1;` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this page it'll tell you all about `date()` [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

The reason you're getting 160 and not 161 is because when you use `date('z')` the date starts from Zero. So it's like like n - 1.

> 'z'   The day of the year (starting from 0)   - 0 through 365

Above quote is from the page I link on the first line

So to get what you need, you'll need to do the following

**Answer:**

```
$day_today = date("z") + 1;
echo $day_today;
```

So you're basically making it start from '1' instead of '0'

Comment: Ok i undertand now.
Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

We need to added `n +1` to adjust for him starting from `1 instead of 0`. –

```
<?php

$day_today = date("z");
echo $day_today+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this :

If you want to set day_today to the correct value :

```
$day_today = date("z") + 1;
echo $day_today;
```

else if you just want to print the correct value :

```
$day_today = date("z");
echo $day_today + 1;
```

you've got n - 1 cause the date start from 0 (not from 1)
set it here :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> 'z'      The day of the year (**starting from 0**)    -     0 through 365